# how to derive boxed classes in Java from primitive types

Tags: java, types, primitive-types

I'm using reflection in Java to call a `Constructor.newInstance()`. Some of the time I encounter primitive types -- which give me trouble when I try to use `Class<T>.cast()` from them.

Suppose I have this:

```
 Class<?> argumentClass = /* obtain class through reflection */;
```

Is there a way to convert `argumentClass` from primitive types (`Integer.TYPE`) to their boxed equivalent (`Integer.class`) when a primitive type is encountered?

Comment: Let me suggest that you go up a level and use java.beans.Statement or Java.beans.Exoression. It does all this stuff for you.